# Application development ON the iPod Touch?

Tags: software-recommendation, ipod-touch, development

I have a pretty long commute to work and own an iPod Touch. I figure it would be nice to do some simple programming on the way. I'm not picky on which language to code on. Also, I usually have no internet connection on my commute so developing and editing on the cloud is out.

I've been looking through the app store but haven't found any apps that offer a "development environment" or an editor with a compiler. It's also not clear to me if I can access the iPod Touch's OS itself and do some coding on it.

Is any development ON the iPod Touch possible? Does an app for this exist?

Comment: Ha! I want to see you hacking special characters, brackets and indenting with the iPod touch. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there will be any with a compiler, due to iOS and App Store restrictions. The best thing on an iPhone or iPod I think would be a text editor to write code (I use [Nebulous](http://nebulousapps.net/) and its Dropbox syncing) and an SSH app (I use [Prompt](http://panic.com/prompt/)) to compile and run the code. Though it might be tough to keep a connection during a commute for SSH.

If you need a computer to SSH to, you could use an Amazon EC2 app to create and use a box on the go. I haven't done that yet, so I don't have a good recommendation, but it's on my list of things to try.

Also, if you have an iPad, [Textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com/) is a fantastic code editor, but it's not available on iPhone or iPod.

Comment: Sadly all ssh client I tried responds slowly to key.

Answer (score -2):

For the iPad you could get [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/) but unfortunately it doesn't run on iPod touch or iPhone.

If your device can be jailbroken and you're willing to do so, then you have many more choices and also direct access to all parts of the iOS.

Comment: Why the down-votes ? Have you ever looked at [iPhone Applications in Python](http://www.saurik.com/id/5)  And Codea is closest to an "editor with a compiler" you can get on a non-jailbroken iPad